# How to Pass and Set values to Usercontrol in wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

How to Pass and Set values to Usercontrol.

Here I have two question regarding a WPF project.

Overview:
In this project, I'm trying to use a Usercontrol as a resources on a canvas and connecting them with each other by LineGeometry. 'MyThumb' class i'm using to make control dragable and control set values.
where i'm using overrided 'OnApplyTemplate' method to pass values on the Usercontrol. To set value i'm using  'Template.FindName'. Here it is returning null.
Now the question is 'how to set values on usercontrol' in the code below:

Another question is related to line color. In the project i'm using LineGeometry to display lines between usercontrols but not able to change line colors.. want to set different lines with different color. 
Here the question is how to change color of existing LineGeometry.

Please have a look to the codes i'm using:

Mythumb.cs

```
 public class MyThumb : Thumb
{
    #region Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(MyThumb), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(MyThumb), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    // This property will hanlde the content of the textblock element taken from control template
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    // This property will handle the content of the image element taken from control template
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public Point MyLocation
    {
        get
        {
            Point nm = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this), Canvas.GetTop(this));
            return nm;
        }

    }

    public List<LineGeometry> EndLines { get; private set; }
    public List<LineGeometry> StartLines { get; private set; } 
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public MyThumb()
        : base()
    {
        StartLines = new List<LineGeometry>();
        EndLines = new List<LineGeometry>();
    }

    public MyThumb(string title, string imageSource, Point position)
        : this()
    {
//Setting ControlTemplate as Usercontrol 'ContactNode'
        ControlTemplate templatex = new ControlTemplate();
        var fec = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContactNode));
        templatex.VisualTree = fec;

        this.Template = templatex;
        this.Title = (title != null) ? title : string.Empty;
        this.ImageSource = (imageSource != null) ? imageSource : string.Empty;
        this.SetPosition(position);
    }

    public MyThumb( string title, string imageSource, Point position, DragDeltaEventHandler dragDelta)
        : this(title, imageSource, position)
    {
        this.DragDelta += dragDelta;
    }
    #endregion

    // Helper method for setting the position of our thumb
    public void SetPosition(Point value)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, value.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, value.Y);
    }

    #region Linking logic
    // This method establishes a link between current thumb and specified thumb.
    // Returns a line geometry with updated positions to be processed outside.
    public LineGeometry LinkTo(MyThumb target)
    {
        // Create new line geometry
        LineGeometry line = new LineGeometry();
        // Save as starting line for current thumb
        this.StartLines.Add(line);
        // Save as ending line for target thumb
        target.EndLines.Add(line);
        // Ensure both tumbs the latest layout
        this.UpdateLayout();
        target.UpdateLayout();
        // Update line position
        line.StartPoint = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.ActualWidth / 2, Canvas.GetTop(this) + this.ActualHeight / 2);
        line.EndPoint = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(target) + target.ActualWidth / 2, Canvas.GetTop(target) + target.ActualHeight / 2);
        // return line for further processing
        return line;
    }

    // This method establishes a link between current thumb and target thumb using a predefined line geometry
    // Note: this is commonly to be used for drawing links with mouse when the line object is predefined outside this class
    public bool LinkTo(MyThumb target, LineGeometry line)
    {
        // Save as starting line for current thumb
        this.StartLines.Add(line);
        // Save as ending line for target thumb
        target.EndLines.Add(line);
        // Ensure both tumbs the latest layout
        this.UpdateLayout();
        target.UpdateLayout();
        // Update line position
        line.StartPoint = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.ActualWidth / 2, Canvas.GetTop(this) + this.ActualHeight / 2);
        line.EndPoint = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(target) + target.ActualWidth / 2, Canvas.GetTop(target) + target.ActualHeight / 2);
        return true;
    } 
    #endregion

    // This method updates all the starting and ending lines assigned for the given thumb 
    // according to the latest known thumb position on the canvas
    public void UpdateLinks()
    {
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.StartLines.Count; i++)
            this.StartLines[i].StartPoint = new Point(left + this.ActualWidth / 2, top + this.ActualHeight / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.EndLines.Count; i++)
            this.EndLines[i].EndPoint = new Point(left + this.ActualWidth / 2, top + this.ActualHeight / 2);
    }

    // Upon applying template we apply the "Title" and "ImageSource" properties to the template elements.
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        // Access the textblock element of template and assign it if Title property defined
        if (this.Title != string.Empty)
        {
            TextBlock txt = this.Template.FindName("tplTextBlock", this) as TextBlock;
            if (txt != null) //getting null here unable to find element..
                txt.Text = Title;
        }

        // Access the image element of our custom template and assign it if ImageSource property defined
        if (this.ImageSource != string.Empty)
        {
            Image img = this.Template.FindName("tplImage", this) as Image;
            if (img != null)
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.ImageSource, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    // flag for enabling "New thumb" mode
    bool isAddNewAction = false;
    // flag for enabling "New link" mode
    bool isAddNewLink = false;
    // flag that indicates that the link drawing with a mouse started
    bool isLinkStarted = false;
    // variable to hold the thumb drawing started from
    MyThumb linkedThumb;
    // Line drawn by the mouse before connection established
    LineGeometry link;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pp = new Point(myCanvas.ActualWidth/2,myCanvas.ActualHeight/2);
        AdNewNode(pp, "ACTION", "/Images/gear_connection.png");

        this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
        this.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Window1_PreviewMouseMove);
        this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp);

    }

    // Event hanlder for dragging functionality support
    private void onDragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Exit dragging operation during adding new link
        if (isAddNewLink) return;

        MyThumb thumb = e.Source as MyThumb;

        Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);

        // Update links' layouts for active thumb
        thumb.UpdateLinks();
    }

    // Event handler for creating new thumb element by left mouse click
    // and visually connecting it to the myThumb2 element

    void AdNewNode(Point nPosition,string nTitle, string nImage)
    {
        MyThumb newThumb = new MyThumb(
                nTitle,
                nImage,     
                nPosition,
                onDragDelta);
        myCanvas.Children.Add(newThumb);
    }

    void Window1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // If adding new action...
        if (isAddNewAction)
        {

            AdNewNode(e.GetPosition(this), "ACTION", "/Images/gear_connection.png");


            // resume common layout for application
            isAddNewAction = false;                
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            btnNewAction.IsEnabled = btnNewLink.IsEnabled = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // Is adding new link and a thumb object is clicked...
        if (isAddNewLink && e.Source.GetType() == typeof(MyThumb))
        {                
            if (!isLinkStarted)
            {
                if (link == null || link.EndPoint != link.StartPoint)
                {
                    Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
                    link = new LineGeometry(position, position);

                    //nodepath=new Path();
                    //nodepath.Stroke = Brushes.Pink;
                    //nodepath.Data = link;   // Here line color is getting change but connectivity getting lost....


                    connectors.Children.Add(link);
                    //myCanvas.Children.Add(nodepath);

                    isLinkStarted = true;
                    linkedThumb = e.Source as MyThumb;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Handles the mouse move event when dragging/drawing the new connection link
    void Window1_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isAddNewLink && isLinkStarted)
        {
            // Set the new link end point to current mouse position
            link.EndPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    // Handles the mouse up event applying the new connection link or resetting it
    void Window1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // If "Add link" mode enabled and line drawing started (line placed to canvas)
        if (isAddNewLink && isLinkStarted)
        {
            // declare the linking state
            bool linked = false;
            // We released the button on MyThumb object
            if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(MyThumb))
            {
                MyThumb targetThumb = e.Source as MyThumb;
                // define the final endpoint of line
                link.EndPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
                // if any line was drawn (avoid just clicking on the thumb)
                if (link.EndPoint != link.StartPoint && linkedThumb != targetThumb)
                {
                    // establish connection
                    linkedThumb.LinkTo(targetThumb, link);
                    // set linked state to true

                    //nodepath = new Path();
                    //nodepath.Stroke = Brushes.Pink;
                    //nodepath.Data = link;

                    linked = true;
                }
            }
            // if we didn't manage to approve the linking state
            // button is not released on MyThumb object or double-clicking was performed
            if (!linked)
            {
                // remove line from the canvas
                //connectors.Children.Remove(link);
                // clear the link variable
                link = null;
            }

            // exit link drawing mode
            isLinkStarted = isAddNewLink = false;
            // configure GUI
            btnNewAction.IsEnabled = btnNewLink.IsEnabled = true;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        //this.Title = "Links established: " + connectors.Children.Count.ToString();
    }

    // Event handler for enabling new thumb creation by left mouse button click
    private void btnNewAction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        isAddNewAction = true;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        btnNewAction.IsEnabled = btnNewLink.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNewLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAddNewLink = true;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Cross;
        btnNewAction.IsEnabled = btnNewLink.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Please try to correct me where i'm doing wrong in this code.

Comment: This is a lot of code and asking two questions. Please consider asking two separate questions on StackOverflow and in each only post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Ok but my main Question is regarding passing values on the Usercontrol in above code.. Thanks !

Comment: Actually it's a testing project which codes i posted so that ppl can understand what exactly i'm doing and trying to ask for..